# c# WPF Application place objects on top of HwndSource

Tags: c#, wpf

In a c# WPF application, I'm using a third-party library that is written in visual c++ (and I'm wrapping it's DLLs with c# classes). One of the methods of the library expects a `IntPtr` of an object to draw on. So what I have done in my application is the following:

```
HwndSource parentSource = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(LiveViewer);
IntPtr parentHWnd = parentSource.Handle;

HwndSource source = new HwndSource(
    0,
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    0,
    50, // x
    50, // y
    300, // width
    300, // height
    "Viewer",
    parentHWnd
);
```

It draws a controller on my WPF window as expected and the third-party library does what it needs to do.

What I want to do is to place other WPF controls (images and buttons) on top of that new `HwndSource` control that was created. But it seems like that control is always on top.

How can I place WPF controls over that control?

Comment: Have you tried playing around the property Panel.Zindex in your controllers?

Comment: Add a popup and see if that goes on top. Then try an adorner and see if that does. https://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/12/wpf-adorners-part-4-ndash-simple-and-powerful-system-for.aspx

Comment: @carloschourio Yes. I have tried that. the `HwndSource` itself does not have a zindex while other WPF controls do.

Comment: @Andy I have tried adding controls via code after adding the `HwndSource` but it is also on the back.

Comment: What if you place your HwndSource inside of a wpf ```UserControl``` and then use it in your main view? Since it's inside a UserControl you'd be able to change the ZIndexProperty of that control

Comment: you can't do that, you must use WinForms controls that hold different Hwnd for each control.

Comment: Did you try a popup and adorner? I don't think an adorner will work but I'm not sure. I think a popup will probably work. Because it's effectively a different window. If neither work then another window with a transparent background might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation you will notice that this is expected behavior:

*HwndHost will appear on top of other WPF elements in the same top-level window.*

What you could probably do is to use SetWindowPos win32 api to change it's state to non-topmost (for ex. using this solution https://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/non-topmost-wpf-popup/)